# How can a guest viewer search my Google drive contents?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

I would like a guest viewer, with or without their own Google account, to be able to search the contents of my drive. Is there any neat way of providing such a search function?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should select all of the folders and files in your drive, press share, and press the "Get Sharable link" button.  Set to "Anyone with the link can view," and anybody with the link will be able to search through your drive and view documents even without a google account.